# Write an array of JSON objects in a text file

Tags: python, json

I have an empty file data.json and I want to populate it with a json array.

I wrote this Python script:

```
import json

myArray = []

first = {}
second = {}
third = {}

first["id"] = 1
first["name"] = "Foo"
second["id"] = 2
second["name"] = "John" 
third["id"] = 2
third["name"] = "Doe" 

myArray.append(first)
myArray.append(second)
myArray.append(third)

with open('data.json', 'w') as my_file:
    strinfgifyied_json_array = # A function that converts myArray to a stringifyed JSON array
    my_file.write(strinfgifyied_json_array)
my_file.close()
```

I am looking for a function that converts an array of JSON objects to a text in order to write them as shown below:

Content of data.json:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Foo"},{"id": 2, "name": "John"},{"id": 3, name: "Doe"}]
```

Comment: See the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: json.dumps() should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a similar solution in my code, using a dictionary! Seeing the content you want, I think it would fit your problem. You really just need to change two small things, how you define the dictionaries and how you write the data in the .json (use the json.dump method)

It would be like this

```
import json

myArray = []

first = dict()
second = dict()
third = dict()

first["id"] = 1
first["name"] = "Foo"
second["id"] = 2
second["name"] = "John" 
third["id"] = 2
third["name"] = "Doe" 

myArray.append(first)
myArray.append(second)
myArray.append(third)

with open('data.json', 'w') as my_file:
    json.dump(myArray, my_file)
```

The output was like this

`[{"id": 1, "name": "Foo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Doe"}]`

Please try and let me know